# Разметка Markdown для модели chatGPT в telegram с пакетом aiogram (Python)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, markdown

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой форматирования текста при разметке Markdown. Когда модель отправляет блоки кода, они не форматируются и получается что-то вроде этого: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал добавить разметку Markdown к ответу, получилось:

```
await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'], parse_mode='Markdown')
```

и блоки кода пришли в порядок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но иногда, когда я пытаюсь отправить свой код и не получаю ответа, в логах видно ошибку как раз в строке ответа

*Can't parse entities: can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 128*

Ещё я иногда могу получить текст вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так же пытался использовать разметку Markdownv2, но меня постоянно просят экранировать символы, хотя они экранированы и я отказался от этой идеи.